# Format Lenovo recovery partition on SSD after making recovery discs

Tags: partitioning, ssd, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo T520 notebook that came with a `Q:` drive labelled **"Lenovo_Recovery"**. I created 4 recovery discs from this partition on DVDs. Now that I have the discs created, can I format my Q partition to regain that space? Would having a SSD affect doing this formatting of the extra partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, the recovery discs will restore all the original partitions if needed.

I see no issue with deleting and formatting that partition on a SSD.

I would boot from the first disc just to be sure it loads the recovery manager and is happy with your hardware and model, before you delete that partition.

Comment: You don't even need to do this in a partition manager.  The Lenovo software will handle it cleanly for you - just try to launch that drive in Windows Explorer and it'll give you the option to reclaim the space.  No fuss, no muss, no worries about breaking the boot partition. :)